# Which is the more secure method between these two for passing the username to the backend after creating the user via Firebase auth?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

After I create the user using `auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword`, I then need to create the relevant documents in Cloud Firestore.

Option 1: if the `auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword` task is successful, call a Cloud Function from the app and pass it the username, UID, and email to create the relevant documents.

```
if (user.isNotEmpty() && email.isNotEmpty() && password.isNotEmpty()) {
                fs.authCreateUser(email, password)
                    .addOnCompleteListener() { task ->
                        if (task.isSuccessful) {
                            Log.e(tag, "createUserWithEmailAndPassword task was successful")

                            fs.CFcreateUser(user, email)
                                .addOnCompleteListener() { task ->
                                    if (task.isSuccessful) {
                                        Log.e(tag, "CFcreateUser task was successful")

                                        val result = task.result!!["result"]
                                        val message = task.result!!["message"]

                                        //If result = 1, go to Groups Activity
                                        //Else, delete the Firebase user so that the list of authenticated users matches the list of users in Firestore
                                        if (result == "1") {
                                            val intent = Intent(this, ActivityGroups::class.java)
                                            startActivity(intent)
                                            finish()
                                        } else {

                                        }
                                    } else {
                                        Log.e(tag, "CFcreateUser task failed")
                                        Log.e(tag, "CFcreateUser task: ${task.exception.toString()}")
                                    }
                                }

                        } else {
                            Log.e(tag, "createUserWithEmailAndPassword task failed")
                            Log.e(tag, "createUserWithEmailAndPassword exception: ${task.exception.toString()}")
                        }
                    }
            }
```

Option 2: if the `auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword` task is successful, update the user's displayName with `user!!.updateProfile` [(from the docs)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users) and then somehow set up a background trigger to create the relevant documents using the displayname as the username.

```
//After the auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword task runs, run the code below 
val user = Firebase.auth.currentUser

val profileUpdates = userProfileChangeRequest {
    displayName = "Jane Q. User"
    photoUri = Uri.parse("https://example.com/jane-q-user/profile.jpg")
}

user!!.updateProfile(profileUpdates)
        .addOnCompleteListener { task ->
            if (task.isSuccessful) {
                Log.d(TAG, "User profile updated.")
            }
        }
```

Not sure which option is more secure, I'm new to Android dev.

Answer (score 0):

> Which is the more secure method between these two?

All requests that are made to Firebase Products like [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore), [Firebase Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database), or [Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions) and are coming from a backend SDK will bypass the security rules entirely. To also mention, that this also includes the [Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup). Security rules **only** apply to web and mobile clients. On the other hand, when using client-side code, you can secure your app using either, [Cloud Firestore Security Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started) or [Firebase Realtime Database Security Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security).

That being said, in my opinion, that's not really about security as it is about efficiency. It's true that you can make the client app do the work, but there is a disadvantage because you can instead do it more efficiently using Cloud Functions. If the client app will do the work, then you'll don't have to pay the cost against the data plan, in terms of data usage and speed. In the case of Cloud Functions, everything is done internally.

Because you are using Firebase Authentication, you can create a Cloud Function to simply solve this problem. So you have to create a function that will be triggered every time something new happens. Here I'm talking about the [trigger of a function on user creation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/auth-events#trigger_a_function_on_user_creation).

That's also the same when we are talking about [Cloud Storage triggers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/gcp-storage-events).

Comment: Hey there. Did my answer help? Can I help you with other information?